# Lightning Community Builder: How to add a new Page into the menu?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, flexipages, community-builder

I have created a new page and populated it with components. Now I want to add a new menu topic and assign the page to it, so when it's clicked the page will be loaded.

When adding a menu item, for the type are 4 options

- Salesforce Object
- Internal URL
- External URL
- Navigation Topic

I think `Internal URL` sounds most promising, but what is the URL of my page, which I have named `test1` ? Or does this work differently?

Answer (score 1):

Internal URL is the right choice. You define the URL when you create the page

[image]

Later if you want to see or edit the URL, pick the page from the Page-Picklist in the top and then make just sure, that under PAGE STRUCTURE the page-name itself is selected. You see the Name and URL (editable) in the property editor at the right sidebar. The URL is labeled `Vanity URL`

[image]